# Creating a binding list projection from a list of search terms

Tags: javascript, windows-8, winjs

I am trying to create a filtered list projection from a collection of search terms.  For instance, if I have one search term, I can do something like this:

```
if (options.groupKey == "filtered") {
    this._items = Data.getItemsFromGroup(this._group);
    var query = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localSettings.values["filters"];
    this._items = this._items.createFiltered(function (item) {
        if (item.content.search(query) > -1) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    })
}
```

But what if the 'filters' local setting is a CRLF delimited list, like this:

```
Cisco
Microsoft
Dell
```

Currently, the search will compare each term to 'Cisco/nMicrosoft/nDell' which obviously won't work. `content.search` doesn't accept an array. Should I just do a loop in the `createFiltered` function somehow? That doesn't seem to be in the spirit of the projection. What is the generally accepted way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about storing and object in the `"filters"` settings where every filter is a property? will that work for you?

```
if (options.groupKey == "filtered") {
    this._items = Data.getItemsFromGroup(this._group);
    var query = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.current.localSettings.values["filters"];
    this._items = this._items.createFiltered(function (item) {
        return Object.keys(query).indexOf(item) > -1;
    })
}
```

The `query` object would be something as follows:

```
{ 
    Cisco: "",
    Microsoft: "",
    Dell: ""
}
```

Does that make sense?

**edit:** made a little change in the code since I believe `if (query[item])` would always return `false` because of javascript *type-casting*

Comment: Thanks! I haven't put this into effect yet, but it looks like it will at least be a good start to what I want to do.